# Jquery finding elements with HTML5 data attributes, using data object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm looking in parent divs for child elements that have a specific HTML5 data attribute. This code was working fine:

`$('#parent').find('*[data-something]').css('color', 'red');`

Then I found out that you can find HTML data attributes using Jquery's data object http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5

So I tried...

`$('#parent').find($("#parent").data("something")).css('color', 'red');`

...and it doesn't work. Does anyone know why?

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/Qct9v/

Note: I have to use `find()` because I need to search child elements.

Comment: You have misunderstood what `.data` does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work because `data()` is not a filter method, it is a getter/setter method used to get/set the data value.

If you want to use jQuery data then try something like

```
$("body").find('*').filter(function(){
    return $(this).data('something') != undefined
})
```

Comment: Thanks! In that case I guess it will be easier to pass the data attribute like I did in the first code. Less code.

Comment: @CyberJunkie yes it is and faster